# Баг MarionetteJs в хроме?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте! У меня проблема, и еще странная. Есть CollectionView. Выше есть фильтры и когда применяю фильтры страница обновляется, хотя по логике не должно, в коде нет такого действия. Еще к url включается знак ?. Вот например при первом открытии http://rns.medside.com/#reviews, затем после применения фильтра (кнопка) страница перерисовывается и адрес становится вот такой - http://rns.medside.com/?#reviews. Самое странное - это то что воспроизводится эта ошибка только в Хроме, а на остальных браузерах все работает идеaльно))

Comment: Код что ль привели бы… Заодно прочитайте про «[mcve]»

Comment: Если проблема была бы в коде таких вопросов вообще не возникало бы)